# javascript to switch multiple css classes on one click for menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a noob who's stuck trying to incorporate a second event into a button click for a menu. The HTML structure is below and I need a button click to not only add/remove a class from the button style but also add/remove "navhidden" from the nav-wrapper div.

```
<button id="clickme" class="buttonstuff"></button>
<div id="nav-wrapper" class="navhidden">nav etc.</div>
```

The button class switcher I'm using is:

```
 var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  [].forEach.call(anchor, function(anchor){
    var open = false;
    anchor.onclick = function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      if(!open){
        this.classList.add('close');
        open = true;
      }
      else{
        this.classList.remove('close');
        open = false;
      }
    }
 });
```

It's a more complicated method than I'm used to but I want to try and learn how to incorporate a second event into it that removes or adds "navhidden" to the div based on whether the button is "open" or not.

I've tried simply adding a second function for the div style but it doesn't work. It was something basic like this:

```
(function($) {
 $('#clickme').click(function() {
    var menuState = $('#nav-wrapper');
      if ($(menuState).hasClass('navhidden')) {
      $(menuState).removeClass('navhidden');
      } 
      else {
      $(menuState).addClass('navhidden');
      }
  });
});
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your document ready shorthand is wrong: `$(function () { /* code here */});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add/remove class, if you're using jQuery you have access to toggleClass:

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#clickme", function (e) {
        $("#clickme").toggleClass("open");
        $("#nav-wrapper").toggleClass("navhidden");
    });
});
```

JSFiddle here answering your first question: http://jsfiddle.net/c8ur4bLu/1/

Comment: Thanks... I removed the `$("#clickme").toggleClass("navhidden");` line because that was adding the same class to the button (and hiding it on click). I'm curious if there's a way to combine the two events into one function. I look at the button switching script and see `open = true`, for example, and think there must be a way to use that to then toggle or add/remove the navhidden style

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, I've updated my answer to toggle the `open` class on the button rather than `navhidden`. Is that what you're trying to do or is it something else?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of using the button class switcher (the first script in my question) and adding something `$("#nav-wrapper").removeClass("navhidden");` right after the `open = true;` line (and addClass after the `open = false` line). In fact I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Have updated to include a link to a JSFiddle outlining your first question, this is vanilla JS so you don't need jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/c8ur4bLu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly use `$(menuState).toggleClass('navhidden');`

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. However as it stands, there are a few issues:

- Your jQuery document.ready shorthand is slightly off, it should be `$(handler)` - where `handler` is some function.
- `menuState` is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to wrap it when referencing jQuery-specific methods (i.e: you can just do `menuState.hasClass()` in your example).
- As others have already mentioned, adding/removing a class can be achieved with jQuery's [toggleclass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

All together, your code can be simplified to:

```
$(function() {

  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    // this is a redundant variable
    //just showing you can access jquery methods directly below
    var menuState = $('#nav-wrapper'); 

    menuState.toggleClass('navHidden');
  });

});
```

Comment: This adds and removes a second instance of 'navhidden' to #nav-wrapper. Using `$("#nav-wrapper").toggleClass("navhidden");` without a variable, as suggested by @timothyclifford, does the job. I guess since this is a one off there's no need to define a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by second instance? As far as I know, the two should be functionally identical. You are correct about the variable though, I was just showing that you can access the jQuery methods directly without needing to wrap in `$()`.